# Extracted by mask raster file with evapotranspiration data not displayed

Tags: arcmap

Should extract a part of raster file containing evapotranspiration data with a polygon.The polygon is that of a barren land which was made with tool ,extract by attributes from my Land use classified raster file and then converted to polygon with Raster to polygon conversion tool.But after doing extract by mask with the same polygon, the output raster is not displayed.I am using Arcmap 10.4 software.

Comment: Aren't you doubling your tasks? The first raster (obtained by extract by attributes) is what you looking for, as far as I understand your question.

Comment: I want to extract the part of evapotranspiration data which coincides with the barren land and display them on screen.